# Best solution to access a function inside the iframe via URL

Tags: javascript

How can I access a function inside my iframe when I only can select the iframe via its URL. I mean I only can select the iframe using this:

```
const component = $(`iframe[src*='https://example.com/example.html']`);
```

Here is a working code I'm using:

```
function executeIframeFunctionFromParent() {

  const component = $(`iframe[src*='https://example.com/example.html']`); // I only have the source url of the iframe and nothing else
  component.attr("id","mainComponentID");
  document.getElementById('mainComponentID').contentWindow.addStructures();

}
```

In the above code, I add an id to the iframe before accessing the function inside but, I wonder if there is a solution not to add an id to the iframe before accessing the function.

Note: the above code is working and there is no cross-domain iframe...

Comment: If the site in the iframe is cross domain, you cannot.

Comment: the above code is working and there is no cross-domain iframe...

Comment: Have you tried pulling the DOM element from the jQuery Object?

Comment: What do you mean...?!

Comment: Try replacing the last two lines with `component[0].contentWindow.addStructures()` and see if that gets you any closer

Comment: That's the answer... WOW...

Comment: I'm glad that worked! :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `component` is a jQuery object while `contentWindow` is a property on native DOM elements. One way to pull the DOM element from the jQuery object is simply adding `[0]` at the end of the variable name. So replace the last two lines of code with this:

```
component[0].contentWindow.addStructures();
```

Another way is to use the `.prop()` jQuery method, as @Taplar suggests:

```
component.prop('contentWindow').addStructures();
```

Comment: or `prop('contentWindow')` should also do the same thing